# Optimal temperatures and light times for pepper plants

Tags: peppers, light, temperature

Day/night temperatures?

How much light is too much?

Right now I have an indoor pepper plant that is usually 80-90F during the day with 18 hours of light. I'm pretty sure I'm overdoing it as the pepper plant is sort of wilting/curling yet is mostly green and does not feel too dry to the touch.

It drops to a nominal 60-70F the other 6 hours and the humidity raises usually from 30% during the day to 60% overnight.

It's also worth mentioning that the LED light I have might be overkill and puts out 500k lumens @ 300W. By comparison, a 4 foot fluro strip I have puts out 100k lumens at 220W with the same light meter at the height of the canopy.

What can I do to optimize my growing environment?

What I have in mind at the moment is significantly more ventilation assistance to keep the ambient air temperature closer to the outside air as well as moving the light up further to the point where the canopy reads around 300k lumens.

Comment: You sure you don't have spider mites?

Comment: Yup, positive. It livens up every night a little bit. It's also been blooming many healthy flowers - they just dry out pretty quickly. Is that typical? This is the first pepper plant I've grown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some modifications, the plant is overall doing much better. I think it's safe to say a peak temperature around 80F is suitable. Light intensity in the range of 200-300k is suitable at 18 hours a day.